# Using Java fields with @NotNull setters and @Nullable getters in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, nullable

I have the following Java class:

```
public class JavaClass {

    private String nullableJavaField;

    @Nullable public String getNullableJavaField() {
        return nullableJavaField;
    }

    public void setNullableJavaField(@NotNull String nullableJavaField) {
        this.nullableJavaField = nullableJavaField;
    }
}
```

The intention is that nullableJavaField may initially be null, but any subsequent set operations should only be with non-null values. It works as intended when called from another Java class:

```
JavaClass jv = new JavaClass();
jv.setNullableJavaField(null); // Produces warning about passing null parameter
```

However, the equivalent Kotlin code produces the error "Val cannot be reassigned":

```
val jv = JavaClass()
jv.nullableJavaField = "Foo" // Produces error "Val cannot be reassigned"
```

As far as I can see, nullableJavaField is not final, so why is Kotlin complaining about assigning to a val? I have searched through similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551177/null-safety-in-legacy-java-libraries-used-in-kotlin-projects) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185237/notnull-and-nullable-contradicting-java-annotations), but am not able to find an answer.

Comment: @user7294900 no, that doesn't fix the problem, because I am not reassigning jv, I am reassigning jv.nullableJavaField

Comment: What is meant by "equivalent Kotlin code"? Do you call the Java class from Kotlin code or did you rewrite the class in Kotlin? Which library belongs `@NotNull` to?

Comment: If the field is should be NotNull, why would you return Nullable value? Users of your code should know that they shouldn't access the null field before initializing. Therefore, I'd mark getNullableJavaField() method as `@NotNull` or you can force user to fill those fields while constructing the POJO if you want to ensure that they don't get null value.

Comment: @Neo I rewrote the class in Kotlin

Comment: @NatigBabayev sure, that's what I would do in a real-world scenario. I was just reading the Kotlin docs and this question came to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *Kotlin* this is not a mutable property. `setNullableJavaField` expects a `String`, while `getNullableJavaField` returns a `String?` and `nullableJavaField` therefore as well. So you have to use the setter directly.

```
val jv = JavaClass()
jv.setNullableJavaField("Foo")
```

Comment: So it isn't mutable because setter and getter use different type?

Comment: Yes. If it was `String` you might get a nullpointer with the getter, if it was `String?` it might get a nullpointer with the setter. If the nullability was the other way around, the property would be of `String`.